# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}\,dx=n!$ by differentiating the equality $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\,dx=\frac{1}{t}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, gamma-function

I'm learning about measure theory, specifically Lebesgue integral, and need help with the following problem:

> Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}\,dx=n!$ by differentiating the equality $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\,dx=\frac{1}{t}$.

Since I had no idea how to solve this problem I first did some research and come across the definition of the Gamma function which I think this problem is related to. I have found that

$$\Gamma(x+1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^xe^{-t}\,dt.$$

Using integration by parts it is actually quiet easy to show that the RSH improper integral evaluates to $$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x).$$

From the above result, substituting successively $x$ with $n-1, n-2,\ldots$ we get that the Gamma function is indeed the factorial function. In particular

$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$

---

My issue is that the problem specifically says to use the fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\,dx=\frac{1}{t}$ and differentiate it. Nowhere in the above prove am I using this equality. How do I show that the improper integral is equal to the factorial function using the given equality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f(t)$ be the function represented by the integral

$$\begin{align}
f(t)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1t
\end{align}$$

Note that the $n$'th derivative, $f^{(n)}(t)$, of $f(t)$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
f^{(n)}(t)&=\int_0^\infty (-1)^n x^n\,e^{-tx}\,dx\\\\
&=(-1)^n\,n! \frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Dividing both sides of $(2)$ by $(-1)^n$ and setting $t=1$ we find that

$$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\,dx=n!$$

as was to be shown!

---

> **NOTE:**

> Here, we justify interchanging the derivatives with the integral.  Note that we have

> $$\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-hx}-1}{h} e^{-tx}\,dx$$

> For $|h|\le t/2$, $\left|\frac{e^{-hx}-1}{h}\right|\le \max\left(\frac2t e^{tx/2},x\right)$ for all $x\ge 0$.  Therefore, the integrand is bounded as

> $$\left|\frac{e^{-hx}-1}{h} e^{-tx}\right|\le \max\left(xe^{-tx},\frac2t e^{-tx/2}\right)$$

> Inasmuch as $\int_0^\infty \max\left(xe^{-tx},\frac2t e^{-tx/2}\right)\,dx<\infty$, the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) guarantees that

> $$\begin{align}
> \lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-hx}-1}{h} e^{-tx}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-hx}-1}{h} e^{-tx}\,dx\\\\
> &=-\int_0^\infty xe^{-xt}\,dx
> \end{align}$$

> The same argument is applicable for taking the second and higher-ordered derivatives.

Comment: Your answer is extremely helpful. There is one point that I don't understand. Calculating the first few derivatives I can see that the $n'$th derivative of $\frac{1}{t}$ is equal to $(-1)^n\,n! \frac{1}{t^{n+1}}$. However, it is unclear to me how you evaluate the expression of the $n'$th derivative for the improper integral. Usually the derivative of the integral of a function is equal to the function itself. Would you mind explaining to me how this is done?

Comment: Yes, but the integration is in $x$ and he is taking the derivative with respect to $t$. He is using $$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^\infty g(x,t) dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} (x,t)  dx$$ which is allowable for the function $g(x,t) = e^{-xt}$ by Leibniz rule.

Comment: @User8128 Thank you. This answers the part of Dr. MV's solution that I didn't understand perfectly.

Comment: @User8128 One thing to keep in mind is that for Leibniz in the case of improper integrals there is an added assumption that the integral (of the derivative) converge uniformly, (just like the case of infinite series). In the case at hand this requires that $t$ be bounded away from zero (which is the case).

Comment: @ReneSchipperus While uniform convergence is indeed a sufficient condition to justify interchanging the integral and differential operations, it is not necessary.  In fact, a weaker sufficient condition is provided by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  I've added a NOTE at the end of the answer that used the DCT to justify the aforementioned interchange.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes that also possible, one thing to keep in mind is that improper integrals are often not Lebesque integrals.

Comment: This integral is only improper in the sense of Riemann integration.  It is a well-defined Lebesgue integral and the DCT only applies in Lebesgue theory.

Comment: (+1) For proving with DCT.

Answer (score 1):

> Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}\,dx=n!$

Without using the requirement, just noting this is a classic "integration by parts" result.
$$
\begin{align}
\int x^n e^{-x}
&=x^n \int e^{-x}-\int nx^{n-1}(\int e^{-x}dx)dx\\
&=-x^ne^{-x}+n\int x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx
\end{align}
$$
and the limits $0$ and $\infty$ make the $x^n e^{-x}$ term disappear.