# How can I Solve this integral by changing to another coordiantes?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

How can we change to polar coordiantes and evalute this integral:

$$
\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \left(x+y\right)
^{k}
e^{-c(x+y)}d{x}d{y}$$

where $c$ is a positive constant, $k$ is a real positive integer.

Now, can we extend our result to the general case given by

$$
\int_{X_{\ell}}  \left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{m}x_{\ell}\right)
^{k}
e^{-c \sum_{\ell=1}^{m}x_{\ell}}  \prod_{\ell=1}^{m }d{x_{  \ell}}
$$

The integration is over $0<{x_{  \ell}}<\infty$ for $\ell=(1,2\cdots m)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use $t cos(\theta)$ and  $t sin(\theta)$ , but that was not useful.

Comment: **Hint :** Substitute $z=x+y$ and integrate by part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I =\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \left(x+y\right)
^{k}
e^{-c(x+y)}d{x}d{y}$$

So I solved using a variable substitution but not polar coordinates.

let $u = x+y$. let $v=x-y$

Therefore $x = \frac{u+v}{2}$ and $y = \frac{u-v}{2}$

$\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}} = -\frac{1}{2}$

The jacobian is $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}} - \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} = -1/4 - 1/4 = -\frac{1}{2}$

$$I =\int_{0}^\infty \int_{-u}^u u^{k}e^{-cu}(\frac{1}{2})dvdu$$

$$I =\int_{0}^\infty u^{k+1}e^{-cu}du$$

For this next part I had to use the solution here:

[Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}\,dx=n!$ by differentiating the equality $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\,dx=\frac{1}{t}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771889/show-that-int-0-inftyxne-x-dx-n-by-differentiating-the-equality)

to get a final answer of

$$\frac{(k+1)!}{c^{k+2}}$$

EDIT:

I'm stuck on the generalization.

Comment: Why the downvote? is this wrong?

Comment: I think someone voted down by mistake.  Your answer is absolutely true. Now can you extend your solution to the general case added to the question.

Comment: Ok,  I want to understand how the integral limita have been change. The outer integral changed to [-u,u] while you keeped the inner summation as it is.

Comment: We need to have $x>=0$ . So $(u+v)/2 >=0$ which means $v>=-u$. We also need $y>=0$ so $(u-v)/2>=0$ So that means $v<=u$. so we have $-u<=v<=u$.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!. I hope I can slove the general case because it is my goal. I can provide you with the final result, but most importantly is how to derive it. The result for the general case is $$\frac{1}{(m-1)!}(k+m-1)! c^{-(k+m)} $$